# Explain the origin of the number of divisors and sum of divisors formulas.

Tags: combinatorics, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

I know the basic formulas which are:

For a number $n = p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k^{a_k}$, we have
$d(n) = ( a_1 + 1 )( a_2 + 1 ) \cdot \ldots \cdot (a_k+1)$ and
$S(n) = \frac{p_1^{a_1+1} - 1}{p_1-1} \cdot \frac{p_2^{a_2+1} - 1}{p_2-1} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{p_k^{a_k+1} - 1}{p_k-1}$

I found some demonstrations but none close to my level of maths understanding.I want a simple description of how those formulas were found. Basically, explain everything.

Comment: Here on math.se we use MathJax, you can have pretty formulas

Comment: Tried to use it for like 20 mins, after that I just left it like that and hoped that somebody would edit it. Thanx a lot.

Comment: You can now press "edit" and have a look at the code :)

Comment: There is only one reliable way to figure out where formulas like these come from—check simple cases.  For example, what do these formulas say when there is only one prime to consider—that is, $n=p^a$?  What if $n$ is the product of two primes, $n=pq$?  What if... well, I won't spoil the fun.  No explanation will be as satisfying to you as one that you come up with on your own.  I don't mean any of this to sound disrespectful; quite the contrary.

Comment: @User-33433 If That would have been an answere, I would have gladly accepted it, since it is probably a better solution than the other 2 :P

Comment: @user1640736 Glad you agree.  You can always submit whatever answer you come up with then accept that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll write about $d(n)$, but this reasoning can probably be extended to $S(n)$.

Every divisor of $n$ will be of the form $p_1^{b_1}\cdots p_k^{b_k}$, where $0 \leqslant b_i \leqslant a_i$. Each choice of $b$ gives a divisor, and vice versa. Every $b_i$ is independent, and has a range of $a_i + 1$ possible values, hence $d(n) = \Pi_{i=1}^k (a_i+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{ x - 1} = x^n + x^{n-1} + \dots + x + 1$. Also note that $(a_1 + \dots + a_n) \cdot (b_1 + \dots + b_m)$ is the sum of all possible combinations of $a_ib_j$. From this you should be able to figure out $S(n)$.

Note that, in the expression of $S(n)$, if instead of the divisors we could have $1$s, that would be $d(n)$. We can make them $1$ if instead of $p_i^{a_i} + \dots + p_i + 1$ you'd have $1^{a_i} + \dots + 1 + 1 = a_i+1$. Thus $d(n)$ can be explained in terms of $S(n)$.